# jQuery parent().find() problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slidetoggle

#### HTML

```
<div class="comments">
    <a class="toggle" href="#">Toggle Comment 1</a><br />
    <div class="comment" style="display:none;">
        Comment1
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a class="toggle" href="#">Toggle Comment 2</a><br />
    <div class="comment" style="display:none;">
        Comment2
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.comment').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/saiprex/ESM4m/

How i can toggle `comment` that's been clicked and not all of them?

Cheers,
Pav

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.comment:first').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/528AW/).

Answer (score 0):

its even simpler, I think, when you clean up your html as well a little bit:
(avoid br)

http://jsfiddle.net/ESM4m/27/

```
<div class="comments">
    <a class="toggle" href="Fork#">toggle</a>
    <div class="comment" style="display:none;">
        Comment1
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a class="toggle" href="#">toggle</a>
    <div class="comment" style="display:none;">
        Comment2
    </div>
</div>




$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It does work, thanks. But there will be html tags between each comment, so i cant use `.next()`