# Identifying closest text input without a unique id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of dropdowns alongside a text box with a plus and minus buttons ( http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-minus-and-plus-in-input) but I'm having some difficulty getting the plus and minus buttons to only change the text box it is next to.

I tried various things such as .parent(), .closest() etc, but couldn't seem to get anywhere. I thought the following post was useful, but again didn't get very far: [jQuery parent().find() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972618/jquery-parent-find-problem)

Here is the code (apologies for style): http://jsfiddle.net/528AW/69/

I'm just trying to get the increase and decrease buttons to effect the input that's next to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I thought perhaps somewhere around here?

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.btn-number').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
                type      = $(this).attr('data-type');
                var input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
                var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
            // around here perhaps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
```

To

```
 var input = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='"+fieldName+"']");
```

See this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/528AW/70/)